# Calling a Member Function Pointer in Static Function

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, static

The title is pretty descriptive. I have stored a non-static pointer to a member function in a vector of a structure that store member function pointers in my class, and I need a static function in the class to call that function.

I have access to the class instance in my static function, but I still can't seem to call the member function through the pointer b/c of an error message `error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member`

The syntax I have now is `(object->*(vector[a].function)) (parameter)`. Simplified code below:

```
class Base
{
    private:
        struct FunctionRelation
        {
            UINT message;
            LRESULT (Base::*function) (HWND, WPARAM, LPARAM);
        };

        static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND window, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);

        std::vector<FunctionRelation>   func_rel;
}
```

The pointer to Base is stored in the USERDATA of the window passed to the `WndProc` function, and thus I have access to the class instance. In `WndProc` I have:

```
Base *user_data = reinterpret_cast<Base *>(GetWindowLongPtr (window, GWLP_USERDATA));

//Loop through our function relations and call those functions. Else, just return DefWindowProc.
if (user_data != NULL) //If it is not directly after we created a window.
    for (int a = 0;a < static_cast<int>(user_data->func_rel.size ());a++)
        if (user_data->func_rel[a].message == msg)
            return (user_data->*(func_rel[a].function)) (window, wparam, lparam);

return DefWindowProc (window, msg, wparam, lparam);
```

Comment: "Doesn't work," isn't enough to go on.  Be precise.

Comment: By definition it's impossible to access a class member without a class instance. Therefore your static function needs an instance. You need to work on that. The fact that in your case the class member is a pointer to member function is irrelevent.

Comment: Now you've told us the error message, it looks like you're trying to access a class member from a static function. Is it possible that `vector` is a member? (In any case, please post enough code to reproduce the problem; the code you've posted is fine given suitable definitions of `object`, `vector`, `a`, `function` and `parameter`, so the problem must be in the definitions of those).

Comment: You can't access the private members like that.

Comment: That's odd, I don't seem to have trouble accessing `user_data->func_rel.size ()`, although `func_rel` is private.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. An answer has been found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have tried the `(object)->*(function) (parameter)` syntax

Try the `(object->*function)(parameter)` syntax instead if `object` is a pointer, or `(object.*function)(parameter)` if it's an object or reference.

UPDATE: now you've posted the error message and some representative code, we can see that the problem is that you're trying to access the class member `func_rel` from a static member function. You'll need to access that via the class pointer:

```
(user_data->*(user_data->func_rel[a].function)) (window, wparam, lparam);
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work. Perhaps because my pointer happens to be stored in a vector of structures which contain the pointers `(object->*(vector[a].function)) (parameter)`.

Comment: @GilgameshOfUruk: That syntax works for me: http://ideone.com/78EoLL. If you still can't get it to work, you should post enough code to reproduce your problem. In particular, the definition of the type in the vector, and the exact type of `object`, `function` and `parameter` would be useful.

Comment: @GilgameshOfUruk: OK, I can see the problem now you've shown us some representative code. I've updated the answer.